# How to write intermediate proof statements inside Coq - similar to how in Isar one has `have Statement using Lemma1, Lemma2 by auto` but in Coq?

Tags: coq, isabelle, coq-tactic, coqide, isar

I wanted to write intermediate lemmas inside Coq proof scripts, e.g., inside SCRIPT in `Proof. SCRIPT Qed.` itself - similar to how one would do in Isar. How does one do this in Coq? e.g.:

```
have Lemma using Lemma1, Lemma2 by auto.
```

I am aware of the `exact` statement and wonder if that is it...but I'd like to have the proof for the statement too like in Isar we have `have by auto` or `using Proof. LEMMA_PROOF Qed.`

To make it concrete, I was trying to do these very simple proofs:

```
Module small_example.

  Theorem add_easy_induct_1:
    forall n:nat,
      n + 0 = n.
  Proof.
    intros.
    induction n as [| n' IH].
    - simpl. reflexivity.
    - simpl. rewrite -> IH. reflexivity.
  Qed.

  Theorem plus_n_Sm :
    forall n m : nat,
      S (n + m) = n + (S m).
  Proof.
    intros n m.
    induction n as [| n' IH].
    - simpl. reflexivity.
    - simpl. rewrite -> IH. reflexivity.
  Qed.

  Theorem add_comm :
    forall n m : nat,
      n + m = m + n.
  Proof.
    intros.
    induction n as [| n' IH].
    - simpl. rewrite -> add_easy_induct_1. reflexivity.
    - simpl. rewrite -> IH. simpl. rewrite <- plus_n_Sm. reflexivity.
  Qed.

End small_example
```

but I wasn't sure how and it wasn't working too well.

---

I'm also interested in `shows` in Coq e.g.

```
shows T using lemmas by hammer.
```

---

Current answers are good in showing that the have and by statements exist in Coq. However, what is crucially missing is 1) the shows statement and 2) the using statements. I'd like to see similar constructs with those in Coq proofs -- especially the using one that works with shows's and have's.

---

What Isabelle seems to be good at is declaring statements as true given a proof and a list of hypothesis. So for example have name: L using l1 by metis. would create the lemma L as a new fact, give it name name but prove it using the tactic metis but crucially depending on the fact l1 as something given for that statement to succeed. So I want to be able to declare things and be checked by a tactic/ATP in Coq.

---

Related:

- I am aware of Czar (https://coq.discourse.group/t/what-is-the-difference-between-ssreflect-and-czar/824) but that is no longer supported in Coq afaik.

Comment: @CharlieParker We need some better context to understand what the answers are missing. Can you add to your question an Isabelle translation of your addition example that illustrates the use of `have` and `shows`?

Comment: @ArthurAzevedoDeAmorim Sure will. I will think through what is a good example of what I want. Let me try to describe it in English here first as I work through an example. What Isabelle seems to be good at is declaring statements as true given a proof and a list of hypothesis. So for example `have name: L using l1 by metis.` would create the lemma `L` as a new fact, give it name `name` but prove it using the tactic `metis` but crucially depending on the fact `l1` as something given for that statement to succeed. So I want to be able to declare things and be checked by a tactic/ATP in Coq.

Comment: @CharlieParker The `assert ... by ...` and `have ... by ...` forms suggested below do almost what you are asking for. If I understand correctly, the only bit that is missing is the `using` part, which seems to guide the proof search of the solving tactic. Coq's generic automation is not as powerful as Isabelle's, but you can write something like `have name: L by eauto using l1`, where `l1` is a lemma to be used by the `eauto` tactic to solve the goal.

Comment: @CharlieParker `eauto using ...` is a standalone tactic, by the way, and independent of `have` or `assert`. You can learn more about it in the reference manual (https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proofs/automatic-tactics/auto.html#grammar-token-auto_using).

Comment: @ArthurAzevedoDeAmorim ah! Interesting, I will check out `eauto`. I admit that what I was thinking of doing was writing my own vernacular in Coq that did what I wanted. I was going to do it by reading how `CoqHammer` worked and what it's API was for receiving lemmas and then based on that attempt to write something in Vernacular + Ltac/Ltac2. I was also planning on getting a full list of all the "automation like tactics" (atps) in Coq and in my ltac function attempt to try them all using the lemmas given until something succeeded (or failed once all options were tried).

Answer (score 6):

You can write `assert <lem>` to prove an intermediate result `<lem>` in the middle of a proof. Other variants are `assert <lem> by <tactic>` to immediately prove `<lem>` using `<tactic>`, or `assert (<lemname> : <lem>)` to give a name to the lemma. Example:

```
Theorem add_comm :
  forall n m : nat,
    n + m = m + n.
Proof.
  intros.
  induction n as [| n' IH].
  - simpl.
    assert (add_easy_induct_1 : forall n, n + 0 = n) by (induction n; auto).
    rewrite -> add_easy_induct_1. reflexivity.
  - simpl.
    assert (plus_n_Sm : forall n m, S (n + m) = n + S m) by (induction n; auto).
    rewrite -> IH. simpl. rewrite <- plus_n_Sm. reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Documentation on `assert`: https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.assert

Comment: That is super cool! Thank you. I have a few questions, will number to make it easier to repond. 1) is it possible to replace the `by` with a new proof environment `Proof. CODE Qed.`? 2) I am curious, how does your suggestion to use `assert` different or `have` or `exact`? Why do you prefer that one? Thanks again!

Comment: 1) If you omit the `by` clause you will get a new subgoal that you can prove interactively (no need for separate `Proof`/`Qed`). 2) `exact` is something else entirely. `have`  is the equivalent of `assert`, with extra features, in the ssreflect style of proof, that I'm just not familiar with.

Comment: I was trying your approach but realized that after the goal is closed, Coq removes/clears the hypothesis automatically from the local context -- even if defined at the top. Do you know why? And how to stop Coq from doing that?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71430579/why-does-coq-remove-clear-my-asserted-lemmas-in-my-proof-after-the-base-case-is

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `have:` construct in the `ssreflect` language of tactics for Coq, with pretty much the same semantics you want, plus a couple of additional nice features related to how this lemma can be used right away (e.g., for rewriting) instead of being given a name.

For a concrete code example, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71428239/1601580

Comment: Thanks for the response! Two questions: 1) What are the additional nice features you had in mind that `have` has? 2) just out of curiosity, the current answers do not mention `exact` and I was curious to know why. Is it not applicable to my case? 3) why is `have` better than `assert`?

Comment: 1) You can concisely specify treatments to perform post sub-lemma specification and proof, such as applying views (to move easily between Prop and bool), removing useless hypotheses, performing simplification or evaluation and more (these are typical of ssreflect tactics); 2) `exact` has nothing to do with `have`, AFAIK; 3) you have to try ssreflect, which i find more structured than standard Coq.

Comment: interesting! that is useful, I will try it. Now I am curious, why is `ssreflect` not the "standard" in Coq like Isar seems to be for Isabelle? Appreciate your time!

Comment: Well, why are there thousands of programming languages? ;) If you are into mathematical specifications and proofs, I suggest you look at ssreflect and the mathcomp libraries (this book may help there: https://math-comp.github.io/mcb).

Comment: what about the `shows` part of my example? (and `using` too)?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not familiar with these constructs.

Answer (score 0):

To provide an example to https://stackoverflow.com/a/70326508/1601580 answer, here is some code example for `have`:

```
  Theorem n_plus_zero_eq_n:
  forall n:nat,
    n + 0 = n.
  Proof.
    intros.
    induction n as [| n' IH].
    - simpl. reflexivity.
    - simpl. rewrite -> IH. reflexivity.
  Qed.

  Theorem Sn_plus_m_eq_n_plus_Sm:
  forall n m : nat,
    S (n + m) = n + (S m).
  Proof.
    intros n m.
    induction n as [| n' IH].
    - auto.
    - simpl. rewrite <- IH. reflexivity.  
  Qed.

  Theorem add_comm :
  forall n m : nat,
    n + m = m + n.
  Proof.
    intros.
    induction n as [| n' IH].
    - simpl. rewrite -> n_plus_zero_eq_n. reflexivity.
    - simpl. rewrite -> IH. rewrite -> Sn_plus_m_eq_n_plus_Sm. reflexivity. 
  Qed.

  (* have proof *)
  From Coq Require Import ssreflect ssrfun ssrbool.
  Theorem add_comm_have:
    forall n m : nat,
      n + m = m + n.
  Proof.
    intros. induction n.
    - simpl.
      have: (forall n, n+0 = n) by (apply n_plus_zero_eq_n). move=> H.
      rewrite -> H. by reflexivity.
    - simpl. rewrite IHn. 
      have: (forall n m: nat, S (n + m) = n + (S m)) by (apply Sn_plus_m_eq_n_plus_Sm). move=> H'.
      rewrite -> H'. by reflexivity.
  Qed.
```

second example based on comment:

```
  From Coq Require Import ssreflect ssrfun ssrbool.
  Theorem add_comm_have':
    forall n m : nat,
      n + m = m + n.
  Proof.
    intros. induction n.
    - simpl.
      have -> //: forall n, n+0 = n by (apply n_plus_zero_eq_n).
    - simpl. rewrite IHn. 
      have -> //: forall n m: nat, S (n + m) = n + (S m) by (apply Sn_plus_m_eq_n_plus_Sm).
  Qed.
```

Comment: If you write `have -> //: forall n, n+0 = n by (apply n_plus_zero_eq_n). `, you don't even need the `move=> H`, `rewrite -> H` and `by reflexivity` (`//` asks to perform trivial simplifications).